# Comparisons in Latin- does this make sense?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice

Here is my sentence:
I'm trying to say that "The gods seemed to favor Romulus because he saw 12 vultures, twice the number of birds that Remus saw."

> Dii Romulō favere visi sunt quia ille duodecim vultures vidit,
> duplicem numerum avium **quem** Remus viderat.

I'm not sure about the "quem" here and if that part of the sentence makes sense.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remus didn't see the "number", but the "birds", so the antecedent of the relative pronoun is *avium*. The form should therefore be *quas* (acc. pl. f.).

(BTW the irregular nom. pl. of *deus* is more commonly spelled *di*, though *dii* apparently occurs too.)

Comment: *Bis quot viderat Remus*?

Comment: @Figulus Interesting idea! I don't know if I've seen a construction like *bis quot*, but it may well be idiomatic Latin.

Comment: @Figulus, Not sure about *bis quot* by itself, but I just came across a bit in Vitruvius (3.4.3) that uses *totidem bis* together with a correlative clause introduced by *quot* to mean 'twice as many as': sed ita columnae in peripteris conlocentur, uti, quot intercolumnia sunt in fronte, totidem bis intercolumnia fiant in lateribus, 'But let the columns on peripteral temples be so arranged that there are twice as many intercolumniations on the sides as on the front.'

Comment: By the way, another, common way to express '2/3/etc. times as much/many' is to use *bis* (or *altero*)/*ter*/etc. *tanto*, sometimes with a comparative. Cicero, Verrines 2.3.102 has: sexiens tanto quam quantum satum sit ablatum esse ab aratoribus, '6 times as much corn as was sown was exacted of the farmers.' In 2.3.225, a comparative is used: reperietis quinquiens tanto, iudices, amplius istum quam quantum in cellam ei sumere licitum sit civitatibus imperasse, 'You will find, judges, that man commanded the cities to supply 5 times as much as it was lawful for him to take for the granary.'